# how to consume soap webservices in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, soap

I am new to node.js and I would like to consume the SOAP webservices in node.js by providing the request and obtain the response. Can anybody guide me as to how to do that. I already checked [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) in github. I am not sure of how to provide my request there and get the response.

Kindly help !

Comment: Hi. I am trying to do the same. I have tried node-soap library but not able to get any success using it. Can you please guide me how did you completed your task?

Comment: @Pritam I have answered. Pls check

Comment: Hi. I have seen your answer. Tried the same. But it is not allowing to access web service. Which SOAP web service are you accessing? I am accessing Microsoft Dynamics NAV SOAP Web Service.

Comment: Does your webservice requires any authentication. If so, then you need to include those as well. I used a simple bottom up webservice created using Java

Comment: Yes. It requires Windows Authentication.Though I have provided correct username and password, it is giving me Error :401.

Comment: Can you please provide your code

Comment: Yes sure. Can We change the platform of communication so that it can be easy to communicate? my skype id is pritam.upadhyay.

Answer (score 2):

```
var soap = require("soap");
var url = 'WSDL URL goes here';
var args = {ls_input:'1'}; // the request goes here
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
 if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
client.Servicename.Portname.OperationName(args, function(err, result) // give appropriate servicename, portname and operation name from the SOAP request
        {
        if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
       }
        console.log(result);
     console.log("describe", client.describe());
               });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [soapjs](https://github.com/jmoyers/soapjs) which is easier to use with nodeJS

Comment: Can you please tell me with respect to node-soap ?

Comment: Everything is provided in Read.me of node-soap . There is also an example at the end. Please try that.